# How can I process the url entered into the browser's address bar using a java program?

Tags: java, url

I want to write a java program to analyse the url entered in to the browser's address bar to check whether its a phishing site or not.I want to write an application that checks every address entered into the address bar.

My Question is how to access the url entered to the address bar and also I want to redirect the browser if the retrieved address is a phishing site. Please help me...

Answer (score 3):

What I can think of is creating a Java Application that acts as a proxy(similar to WebScarab). You parse the HTTP requests and get the URL from there. Aside from that, I don't know of a way of accessing the browser's address bar if you are developing a standalone application. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the browser's URL bar from an external application.

AFAIK, you can't access the browser's URL bar from a trusted Java applet (or an untrusted one).

You can't access the browser's URL bar from untrusted Javascript.

You *may* be able to access the browser's URL bar from a trusted Javascript plugin, but this plugin won't be portable across different browsers.

Your best bet (IMO) is to create a proxy HTTP server that checks the request URLs for phishing sites.  Then get the user to configure his browser to always use that proxy.  The proxy could run on the user's machine, and you could implement it in Java using one of the existing HTTP protocol stacks for Java.